# Função desenfileirar em C

Tags: c

Pessoal tenho que fazer uma função desenfileirar. Receba do usuário: -1 para desenfileirar um elemento ou 2 para enfileirar um elemento Ou seja o usuário para enfileirar tem que digitar a opção 2 e depois entrar com os valores e ir adicionando assim. Se ele quiser retirar um valor da fila o usuário vai digitar -1 e vai retirando, retirando até esvaziar.

Eu fiz a enfileirar, quero saber como faz a desenfileirar.

```
#define TAM_FILA 10

typedef struct
{
    int inicio, fim;
    int fila[TAM_FILA];
} tipo_fila;

int desenfileirar(tipo_fila *fila)
{
    //printf("\n\n Desenfileirar ...\n");

    if(fila->inicio==fila->fim)
    {
        printf ("Fila vazia!");
    }
    else
    {
        /*int i;
        for(i=0; i < TAM_FILA; i++)
        {
            fila->fila[i]=fila->fila[i+1];
        }
        fila->fila[fila->fim]=0
        fila->fim--;*/
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O codigo comentado esta parcialmente correto ... o unico problema é que ele pode acessar um elemento fora do array ... tente corrigir isso

Comment: então voltei a usar ele, e da erro quando chamo ele.